# Are perl packages autovivified? How exactly do they work?

Tags: perl

I was trying to figure out whether it was possible to dynamically create a Perl package, so I wrote a simple test program.

```
eval "package foobar;";

$foobar::baz = 4;
print $foobar::baz;
```

The program prints `4`. Then I tried

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

eval "package foobar;";

$foobar::baz = 4;
print $foobar::baz;
```

The program didn't crash and wasn't rejected (and still prints `4`), despite the fact that the `foobar` package isn't known to exist until runtime.

Then I tried

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

$foobar::baz = 4;
print $foobar::baz;
```

and Perl still happily prints `4`

I am now thoroughly confused. I always thought that packages had to be created explicitly and didn't just spring into being. How exactly do they work? Are there pragmas out there that can emit a warning when a package is 'used' without being 'declared' via `package`?

Comment: Yes, they are created whenever they are referenced. You can remove the `package foobar` statement and your code would still work.

Comment: You know how when you have `strict` on you get complaints about "explicit package names?" That's exactly what `$foobar::baz` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a sense, packages are nothing but keys in a hash that happens to be a symbol table. You can see this by examining the hash `%foobar::` after you set `$foobar::baz` in your example code. After that, you can start looking at `%::`. It's possible to do interesting (as well as hard to understand and tricky to debug) things by messing directly with the symbol tables.

The documentation page to read for all this is `perlmod`.

Answer (score 3):

> *Are perl packages autovivified?*

Yes.

> *How exactly do they work?*

`package` can indeed be used to create a package.

```
$ perl -E'
    BEGIN { say $main::{"Foo::"} ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist"; }
    { package Foo; }
    BEGIN { say $main::{"Foo::"} ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist"; }
'
doesn't exist
exists
```

But it's primary purpose it to specify where unqualified package variables are located.

As you've discovered, As soon as a symbol is referenced in a package, that package (and any parent package) are automatically created if necessary.

```
$ perl -E'
    BEGIN { say $main::{"Foo::"} ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist"; }
    $Foo::bar;
    BEGIN { say $main::{"Foo::"} ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist"; }
'
doesn't exist
exists
```

`$Foo::bar` is referenced at compile-time, which is why `BEGIN` was used to run code before the line `$Foo::bar` was compiled.

> *Are there pragmas out there that can emit a warning when a package is 'used' without being 'declared' via package?*

I'm pretty sure there isn't. I'm pretty sure that would require code in Perl itself (as opposed to an extension downloadable from CPAN).

However, you are likely to run into the "used only once" warning.

```
$ perl -we'use Data::Dumper; $Data::Lumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper("\n"));'
Name "Data::Lumper::Useqq" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
$VAR1 = '
';

$ perl -we'use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper("\n"));'
$VAR1 = "\n";
```

Of course, if you avoid using fully-qualified names (by providing better interfaces), you avoid the issue entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it *autovivified*, as that generally refers to the creation of anonymous arrays and hashes when they are referenced. But there is no need to declare packages, and all `package` does is define the *default* package where all subsequent subroutines and `our` variables will be stored if they are not fully-qualified